# Finding the Roots of Cubic (Boas 2.14.25)

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I'm working my way through Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences  and came across the following problem:

---

Use a computer to find the three solutions of the equation $x^3−3x−1=0$. Find away to show that the solutions can be written as $2 cos(\pi/9)$, $-2cos(2\pi/9)$, $-2cos(4\pi/9)$.

---

I can easily find the roots numerically and subsequently check that they do, in fact, match the expressions given, but I'm at a loss as to how find the roots analytically.

Based on the section that this problem is from, I suspect that I should replace $x$ with a complex exponential, say $e^{iy}$, and use De Moivre's formula.  However, no amount of algebra has gotten me any closer to even one of these solutions.

Any input on whether this is correct thinking or how to go about this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible typo: $2\cos (2\pi/9)$ isn't a root (see [WA](http://po.st/sI1fHX)), but $2\cos (5\pi/9)$ is (see [WA](http://po.st/zXpKTh)).

Comment: Yep typo. The values found in the book are there now, but $2cos(5\pi/9)=-2cos(4\pi/9)$

Comment: That works. I'm still curious whether one can find a complex algebra approach, but with that discrepancy resolved I'd say the method below works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the general cubic equation
$$x^3+px+q=0,$$and let
$$x=2a\cos t=a(e^{it}+e^{-it}).$$
Developing, you get
$$x^3+px+q=a^3(e^{3it}+3e^{it}+3e^{-it}+e^{-3it})+ap(e^{it}+e^{-it})+q=0.$$
If you make
$$3a^3+ap=0,$$
all terms in $e^{\pm it}$ cancel out and you are left with
$$a^3(e^{3it}+e^{-3it})+q=0,$$i.e.
$$\cos3t=-\frac q{2a^3},$$
where
$$a=\sqrt{-\frac p3}.$$
In the given case, $a=1$, $\cos3t=\frac12$, $3t=\pm\frac\pi3+2k\pi$, $t=\frac{\pm1+6k}9\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was trying to do but had trouble getting terms to cancel.  I suppose that this serves as a reminder that when all else fails, do the general case.

Comment: Yep, and if $p$ is positive, you need to resort to more complex algebra. And if $cos>1$, use the $cosh$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x=2\cos\phi$ and recall the triple-angle identity $\cos 3\phi=4 \cos^3\phi-3\cos \phi$.

Comment: That will do it.  Thank you.

Comment: That suggests that this is purely coincidental since it relies on triple-angle identity, correct?

Comment: It does, which bothers me a bit; I too had expected an explanation along the lines of complex algebra. But right now I see no deeper meaning to it.

Comment: All cubic equations can be transformed into a form amenable to solution in this way, by making an appropriate change of variables and scaling.